# nodejs setTimeout not working when called from cron job

Tags: node.js, cron

I am writing a nodejs program, which needs to upload local sensor information to central database every 15 seconds. since the minimum cron interval is 1 minute, i am calling the the upload routine 4 times like this

```
function uploadToDatabase() { /* blah blah blah */ }  

setTimeout(uploadToDatabase, 1*1000);
setTimeout(uploadToDatabase, 15*1000);
setTimeout(uploadToDatabase, 30*1000);
setTimeout(uploadToDatabase, 45*1000);
```

this function getting called as intended when i run this in command like like

```
node uploader.js
```

but when this is called from cron job this function uploadToDatabase never called?

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct for `node` and the `uploader.js` file when started by `cron`?

Comment: Yes, using full path inside crontab. the script gets executed, but just the timeout doesnt works. looks like it has something to do with event-loop.

Comment: Is the script just exiting immediately?

Comment: @WiredPrairie yes, the script stops immediately (ignores pending timeout)

Comment: Throw the entire block in a `try { } catch(e) { console.log(e); }` ... is there an error?

Comment: @WiredPrairie . thanks for helping. no error, setTimeout returns valid object also. :(

Comment: Could you add any more of your code (the stuff inside setTimeout shouldn't matter if you're sure it's not throwing an exception)? The process should not exit. I just tried it to verify, and it exits only after the final `setTimeout` completes.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, basically the code just POSTs data to remote url.this code deployed in RaspberryPI using Raspbian OS

Comment: Does the code work elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cron job. Just run it in node and have a loop that executes every 15 seconds.

Comment: yeah, forever+node.js+setInterval should do the same. If you want to do something every hour or so then cron is a good idea, but every 15s...

Comment: @TheBronx for some reason it has to be managed thru cron, mine is small task in a big system that manages everything using cron scheduling.